# Size of data page in SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server

To my knowledge SQL server, the data page size is 8086. However, my test result is not adding up.

Test scripts

```
CREATE table dbo.Heap
(
  Val varchar(8000) not null
);

--Fill it with half the page size data
insert into dbo.Heap    
  SELECT replicate('0',4043)

SELECT  [avg_page_space_used_in_percent],[min_record_size_in_bytes],[avg_record_size_in_bytes],[max_record_size_in_bytes]
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),object_id(N'dbo.Heap'),0,null,'DETAILED'); 

SELECT
      bf.*   
    FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors bf
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS au
    ON au.[allocation_unit_id] = bf.[allocation_unit_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p
    ON au.[container_id] = p.[partition_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i
    ON i.[index_id] = p.[index_id] AND p.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
WHERE p.[object_id] > 100 
    and [database_id] = DB_ID () AND p.[object_id]=OBJECT_ID('Heap')
```

[image]

`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` tells me half the data page is full. As per `sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors` the page has 4040 free space.

What I don't understand is `max_record_size_in_bytes`+`Free_space_in_bytes= 8096`
where is the extra 10byte coming from?

Platform: SQL 2019

Comment: In SQL Server, the page size is 8-KB (8192-byte). Each page begins with a 96-byte header. `8192 - 96 = 8096` How did you get 8086?

Comment: As always.. my mistake.. data payload part is 8096. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Paul Randal's [anatomy of a page](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) and [anatomy of a record](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record/) articles, the 8K data page structure for your example is as folows:

```
SELECT
      96 --page header
    + 2 --Two bytes of record metadata (record type)
    + 2 --Two bytes pointing forward in the record to the null bitmap
    + 0 --Fixed length portion of the record, containing the columns storing data types that have fixed lengths
    + 2 --Two bytes for count of columns in the record
    + 1 --Variable number of bytes to store null bitmap
    + 2 --Two bytes for the count of variable-length columns
    + 2 --Two bytes per variable length column, giving the offset to the end of the column value
    + 4043 --column data
    + 4040 --page free space
    + 2 --record slot array
--total 8192
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Appreciate your help.